# How can I avoid printing on new line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of students and their corresponding grades:

```
Johnson Smith
93
Maryanne James
80
Stanton Chase
45
Mildred Morris
90
George Deitz
89
Maisie Kling
79
```

I need an "F" to be displayed for grades below 60, but when I put my `if` statement it puts the "F" in a new line below the 45 rather than next to it. 
I have:

```
if stu_points < 60:
   print("\t\t\t\tF")
```

It keeps displaying like this:

```
Johnson Smith       93
Maryanne James      80
Stanton Chase       45
                    F
Mildred Morris
```

This is my code:

```
def main():
    file_students = open("students_points.txt", "r")
    stu_name = file_students.readline()

    num_stu = 0
    f_students = 1
    pass_students = 5/6

    print("Student\t\t\tPoints\t\tGrade")
    print("------------------------------\n")
    while stu_name != "":
        stu_name = stu_name.rstrip("\n")
        stu_points = file_students.readline()
        stu_points = int(stu_points)
        print(stu_name,"\t\t",stu_points, sep="",)
        num_stu += 1

        if stu_points < 60:
            print("\t\t\t\t\tF")

        stu_name = file_students.readline()

    file_students.close()
    print()
    print("Number of students processed=", num_stu)

main()
```

Comment: use `end=''` in print statements before the `if`. Add an `else` to your `if` that just prints a new line. Edit your question to show how you are printing the first three lines.

Comment: Okay I added my code.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function appends a new line by default, so you should use.

```
print("Hello ", end="")
print("world.")
```

Output:

```
Hello world.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's suppose to display the F next to it when the if statement is valid. My if statement is if stu_points < 60: print ("\t\t\t\t\tF")  I tried your suggestion but it just puts it on the line below 45 in front of Mildred Morris.

Comment: Without stating how this fits to the OP's situation, it is not much of a help.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** From your inadequate description of how your file is structured, along with your badly written code, I figured out that your file has names and marks on separate lines.

Here is a complete, well-written code you can use.

#### Caution: study the code well, instead of just copy-pasting, and try learning from it.

```
def main():
    lines = open("students_points.txt").readlines()
    records = []
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        records.append((lines[i].strip(), int(lines[i+1])))

    print('{:20}{:>6} {}'.format('Student', 'Points', 'Grade'))
    print('--------------------------------')
    for name, marks in records:
        if marks >= 60:
            print('{:20}{:>6}'.format(name, marks))
        else:
            print('{:20}{:>6} F'.format(name, marks))

main()
```

Here, I have used [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting). With `{:20}`, I am specifying a field [width](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#grammar-token-width) of 20 for `name`, and with `{:>6}`, I am specifying a width of 6 and right [aligning](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#grammar-token-align) the value of `marks`.

Output:

```
Student             Points Grade
--------------------------------
Johnson Smith           93
Maryanne James          80
Stanton Chase           45 F
Mildred Morris          90
George Deitz            89
Maisie Kling            79
```

Comment: @AllanGrand Then you should mark this answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Click on the hollow tick mark next to the answer to do that.